# $emit event not working with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I got new requirement to implement, so I had to render the directive based on the condition.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <body-dir>

    <icon-dir> 
    </icon-dir>

    <filter-dir>
     </filter-dir>

    <widget-dir ng-if="someCondition">
    </widget-dir>

  </body-dir>
</div>
```

From above directive structure, I'm trying to render `'widget-dir'` based on the `someCondition` property.

Todo that I'm emitting the event from  `<filter-dir>` and catching the event in `widget-dir` which is not working.

**If I remove the ng-if it's working fine.**

Below things I understood from various sources:

- ng-if creating the new scope.
  But according to the angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), the newly created scope will inherit from the parent.

  So, it should share the `body-dir` scope?
  If it is shared then whatever we are emitting the event from  `<filter-dir>`, should catch in `widget-dir` ?

Above functionality is working fine If I remove the `ng-if`.
Here, I couldn't understand what exactly happening.

I know `$emit` event purpose is to catch the event in a parent.
Earlier I caught the event in a sibling as it shared from the parent scope(Is this is best practice ?).

**Update:** Here one more thing I noticed that if I put `ng-if` on directive child element(Not to the directive) then it's working as expected.
In below code I put `ng-if` on template element.
Here, just I'm trying to understand how the angular scope works with `ng-if`.

```
angular.module('app').directive('widgetDir', function(){
  return {
    template: '<br><span ng-if="true">I\'m in "ng-if"</span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  scope.$on('evt-filter', function(evt, data){
    alert(data);
  });
    }
  }
})
```

Could anyone please clear this.

**Issue reproducible** [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIoD1NtBRLyBUA58eXCZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: 
May be its NOT in the DOM when you emit it.Try ng-show if you can.

Option 2:

$broadcast instead of $emit
In your controller do:

> $rootScope.$broadcast('PHOTO_UPLOADED', photo);

and in your directive, catch the broadcast event via

> $rootScope.$on('PHOTO_UPLOADED', function(event, data) {
>            thumbnail = data;
>         });

Comment: @option1: it will work if I put ng-show because it won't remove from Dom where ng-if do and creates new scope.

Comment: Dom element is there I have verified

Comment: Option2: if I want to broadcast the event I have to emit the event to parent and from parent to child have to broadcast.

Comment: One more thing I don't wanna broadcast the event on rootcope.

Comment: Can you provide a link to plunker , jsfiddle?

Comment: Issue reproducible in above link.
Could you please check once

Comment: I did. Its weird. I don't know the reason but will definitely share once i know

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have updated my question, could you please have a look so that you might help me with this